# Cannot find symbol Integer.valueOf(int)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have an old project which works well before, but I open it today and find compiler told me that `'cannot find symbol Integer.valueOf(int)'` or `'cannot find symbol Integer.toHexString(int)'`.

It seems that there is something wrong with java.lang.Integer. 
I use IntelliJ and it compile failed as above, but Eclipse works fine.
Besides, I use paste the same code to a new IntelliJ project, it also works fine.

Is there anything wrong with configuration of my old IntelliJ project? Anyone meet this question before?

Sample code are following:

```
public class ContainerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List numbers = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)); // cannot find Integer.valueOf(int) here
        ListIterator listIterator = numbers.listIterator();

        while (listIterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("index" + listIterator.nextIndex() + " : " +listIterator.next());
            listIterator.add(100);
        }

        System.out.println(numbers);
    }
}

public class BinaryFileTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        DataInputStream reader = null;

        try {
            String filename = "./target/classes/io/TreeInfo.class";
            reader = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(filename)));
            int i = 0, k;

            while (reader.available() != 0 && i++ < 4) {
                System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(k = reader.read())); // here
                System.out.println(k);
            }

            reader.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using older java version as well ?

Comment: According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-int-, `Integer.valueOf(int i)` was added to Java in 1.5.  Check what version of Java IntelliJ thinks you're using.

Comment: i am sure intellij use jdk1.8 to compile my project, it's log shows that "Information:javac 1.8.0_101 was used to compile java sources" , my eclipse use this version to compile the same class, but find compile success. beside, there are jdk7 and jdk8 in my machine, both of them are above jdk5.

Answer (score 0):

It is common when you use a version that doesn't support that methods, to fix this, make sure that you are using the same version in both ides (eclipse and IntelliJ). In IntelliJ you can setup that in `Project Settings > Project` choose the correct `Project SDK` version, the same way in `Project Settings > Modules` choose your project, click on `Dependencies` tab and choose the correct `Module SDK` version.